GitHub Actions (docker-run-action): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon
I created a workflow on a GitHub Enterprise server. I want to build & push the container with the docker/build-push-action and before push I want to run some tests in the container.
My workflow file looks like this:
name: Docker Image Build & Push

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: write

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build & Push Container
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, docker]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker Meta
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v5
        with:
          images: |
           registry.private/user/image
          tags: |
            type=schedule
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=ref,event=pr
            type=semver,pattern={{version}}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
        with:
          driver: docker-container

      - name: Login to Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          registry: registry.private

      - name: Docker Build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          push: false
          context: .devcontainer
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}

      - name: Run some commands in the container
        uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
        with:
          image: registry.private/user/image
          run: whoami && pwd
      
      # Put here the step for the push



Everything works fine except the execution of the addnab/docker-run-action@v3 action. I got the following error message:
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

I found this issue on GitHub, but there was no working solution.

Do you need some third party action for that? Just - run: docker run ....

I would prefer to use a reusable action from the marketplace. If this is not possible, I have to use the docker run ... command. But since I want to work with multiline commands, the reusable action would be easier to use

...https://yaml-multiline.info/. That whole reusable action is just a thin wrapper around... docker run. Why be beholden to some random third party for fixes?

you're trying to run docker inside docker aka dind.
It is possible but you need to mount docker socket
/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
example :
container:
  image: docker image
  options: -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock


The action from addnab/docker-run-action does exactly this option. In my case this mount happened, but the docker socket is still not available

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comments, the docker run workes pretty well, also with multiline commands.

.yaml-multiline.info. That whole reusable action is just a thin wrapper around... docker run.

My step looks now like this:
      - name: Run Tests in Container
        run: >
          docker run ${{ needs.build.outputs.tag }} bash -c "
          whoami &&
          whoami &&
          ls -la"

